# Can't change outputStyle with gulp-pug plugin

Tags: html, gulp, pug

```
gulp.task('pug-general', function(){
    gulp.src('bundles/pug/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({
        outputStyle: 'compact'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('page/'));
});
```

I've been looking for a way to change output style for pug templates because, when it compiles it outputs a single line html file. Although I've written `outputStyle: 'compact'` I was just trying to see if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pug has a "pretty" option. However it's set to false by default so if you would like more white space collapsed, you might like to try this gulp package https://github.com/jonschlinkert/gulp-htmlmin

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I also found a solution with `pug-html-prettify` plugin